# How do I suppress unwanted ui-router 'otherwise' transitions in my unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

Using the latest `@ui-router/angularjs`, I have a state configured with an `otherwise` block:

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page');`

I also have a `.run()` block that uses a `$transitions.onBefore()` hook to perform a security check, similar to [ui-router's sample app](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs/blob/master/app/global/requiresAuth.hook.js):

My problem is that any of my Karma tests that run trigger the following:

- The `.otherwise()` block runs
- Which in turn tries to navigate to `/page`
- Which causes the `.run()` block to run
- Which performs `$http` service calls, among other unnecessary work

This happens for any test that runs `angular.mock.module('module')`, even if I'm not explicitly testing any routing behavior. Even if I'm just loading `$componentController` and nothing else.

I *could* get around this by adding `$httpBackend` mocks for the service calls happening in my `.run()` block, but I feel like there should be a better way.

So, what's the best practice for testing once you have default routing and `.run()` blocks as ui-router recommends?

Comment: The best practice is to not include ui router module in tests at all and stub all router services.

Comment: @estus How would that work? Say my module `app.foo` includes a component `Foo`, routes defined in `FooConfig`, and a hook defined in `FooRun` - how would I test `Foo` in isolation?

Comment: [Like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637494/3731501). Then router config can be tested separately [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497584/3731501).